# JavaFX: DialogPane won't display background Image

Tags: java, css, javafx

fxml file for the dialogPane

```xml
<DialogPane  xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
            fx:controller="ToDoListMatt.ErrorDialogController" >

    <content>
        <GridPane fx:id="ErrorDialogPane" prefWidth="300" prefHeight="200" alignment="CENTER" hgap="10" vgap="10" >

            <TextField fx:id="errorTextArea"  prefHeight="10" prefWidth="150" style="-fx-background-color:red"/>
        </GridPane>
    </content>


</DialogPane>
```

My function where will the `DialogPane` will pop up

```
 public static void showAlert(String errorType) {
    try {
        try {
            Dialog<ButtonType> dialog = new Dialog<>();

         dialog.initOwner(DialogController.dialogBG.getScene().getWindow());
    dialog.setTitle("Ooopsie");
    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();


            dialog.getDialogPane().setContent(fxmlLoader.load());
            dialog.getDialogPane().getButtonTypes().add(ButtonType.OK);
            dialog.show();
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }catch (NullPointerException e){

    }


}
}
```

My css code

```css
#ErrorDialogPane{
-fx-background-image: url("Image2.gif");

}
```

Basically, I used a DialogBox as an alternative to `Alert` because of customizations. Things I've done already:

1. I already double-checked the URL of the Image I will use. The path is correct because I tried changing my `.root`(Main window) background by using the same path of the image.
2. I'm not sure about what `initOwner` does. Can this affect it?

I can send the program for ya'll to double check. I'm creating an ToDoApp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to link the css file to your fxml like:

```
<DialogPane  xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
                fx:controller="ToDoListMatt.ErrorDialogController"
                stylesheets="@yourCssCode.css">
```